# CloudKit, can't save NSDate to Date/Time field, "Invalid Date"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

I can't seem to save an NSDate to cloudkit, in the dashboard, it shows an `Invalid Date`.

I've tried sending up various combinations of an `NSDate` e.g. `[NSDate date]` etc.

Other values save fine.

I've also tried manually adding a date to the dashboard and this shows fine.

I thought it might be a bug in cloudkit, any suggestions, where I go from here?

Although I could file a radar, I'm in a bit of a rush with my app.

Here's my code...

```
CKRecordID *recordId = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName: record_name_guid
                                               zoneID: [self customZone]];

CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType: @"students" recordID:recordId];

record[@"enroll_date"]      = [SharedCommon convertDBStringDateToNSDate: enroll_date];
record[@"best_tbl"]         = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: best_tbl];

[recordsToUpload addObject:record];

CKModifyRecordsOperation *op = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] 
    initWithRecordsToSave: records
    recordIDsToDelete: deleteIds];

op.savePolicy = CKRecordSaveAllKeys;

op.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray *savedRecords, 
       NSArray *deletedRecordIDs, NSError *operationError)
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this too.  With the old dashboard my dates were fine.  I'm thinking it's a bug.